# Finding probability interval from cummulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've been asked to find the cumulative distribution function of :

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
c(1-x^2) & -1.5 \le x \le 2 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I'm attempting to understand the intuition of applying the cumulative distribution function from above question question.

I made use of following questions/answers/references :

[to find the distribution function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93386/to-find-the-distribution-function)

[Find C and the distribution function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791115/find-c-and-the-distribution-function/1791122#1791122)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

The cumulative distribution function will be ? :

$$F(x)=\int_0^x{c(1-x^2)}dx$$

From the cumulative distribution function how to find find $P(-.5 \lt X \le .75)$ ?

Comment: Note that $f(3)=-c$ and $f(1)=c$. This makes clear that $f(x)$ cannot be a PDF. A PDF does not take negative values.

Comment: Maybe the domain is meant to be $0 < x < 2$? Also, the last line $P(-.5 \lt X \le .75)$ either is a trick question or another typo since $X > 0$ by definition.

Comment: @blue-sky    I suggest that you review integration of polynomials and integration by substitution.   A solid foundation of calculus knowledge will help you to learn and understand cumulative distribution functions and, more generally, continuous distributions.  Often, higher level courses in mathematics help you solidify the knowledge learned in the prerequisite courses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid confusion, use $F(x)=\int_0^x c(2-s)^3\mathsf d s$

Now, $\int c (2-s)^3\mathsf ds=\dfrac{-c (2-s)^4}{4}$, so

$$F(x)=\dfrac{-c}{4}{\Big[(2-s)^4\Big]}_{s=0}^{s=x}\mathbf 1_{x\in(0;\underset{?}{\tiny\boxed{3}})}+\mathbf 1_{x\in [\underset{?}{\tiny\boxed{3}};\infty)}$$

---

Though, as DrHab notes, the given function is negative over the latter part of its domain, so cannot be a probability density function.  That 3 is likely a typographical error; perhaps it is mean to be 2?.